# Sort example from C++ Programming Language

Tags: c++, static-cast

I am going through the following example code in "C++ Programming Language":

```
typedef int (*CFT) (const void*, const void*);

void ssort(void* base, size_t n, size_t sz, CFT cmp) {
    for (int gap = n / 2; 0 < gap; gap /= 2) {
        for (int i = gap; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i - gap; 0 <= j; j -= gap) {
                char* b = static_cast<char*>(base);
                char* pj = b + j * sz;
                char* pig = b + (j + gap) * sz;

                if (cmp(pig, pj) < 0) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < sz; k++) {
                        std::swap(pj[k], pig[k]);
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int cmp(const void* a, const void* b) {
    return *(static_cast<const int*>(a)) - *(static_cast<const int*>(b));

}
```

Can anyone explain what these casts to char* are about? How can we use char* to point to value of any type?

Comment: Ok, found it (e.g. 4th edition page 334). Note that he used it as an example of what *not* to do in C++, besides this being "normal" C-style.

Comment: Use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) - that link has an example similar to your needs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember this is an example to demonstrate how **not** to do things in **C++** by illustrating the weaknesses in `C` programming when dealing with *generics*.

**Quote:** ***The C++ Programming Language*** (4th Edition p 334)

> This style of code is common in C, but it is not the most elegant way
>   of expressing this algorithm in C++

**However:**

```
char* b = static_cast<char*>(base);
char* pj = b + j * sz;
char* pig = b + (j + gap) * sz;
```

The *reason* the `void` pointers are cast to `char` pointers is because you can't do pointer arithmetic on `void*`.

Pointer arithmetic works in *units* of the *size* of the object the pointer points to. So to do pointer arithmetic the compiler needs to know the *type* of the pointer so it can know how to add and subtract from its value.

This is not possible with `void*` because `void` has no size. By accepting `void*` parameters the original *type* has been lost.

To get round this the algorithm casts the `void*` to `char*`. The `char*` 
works in size units of *one*. The function then expects the user to pass in the *actual* size of each element as another parameter.

The compiler has no trouble doing arithmetic on the resulting `char*`.

Because the `ssort()` function does not know the *type* of the elements it is sorting the caller needs to also *pass in* their own function to do the comparison between elements. Note that the *passed in* function casts the `void*` parameters to the correct type.

This works because the person calling the `ssort()` function knows the *type* to be sorted and the `ssort()` function doesn't need to.

This puts a lot of burden on the function caller and there is a *lot* of room for mistakes leading to subtle or not so subtle bugs.

**This type of programming should be *avoided like the plague* in `C++`**.

**To summarize:**

The `ssort()` function casts the `void*` to `char*` so that it can do pointer arithmetic to locate which elements need comparing.

The *caller* passes in their own function (cmp) that casts the `void*` to the *correct type* in order to make the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

`static_cast<T>` simply try to convert a type to type `T`. Look at the example here -

```
float f = 12.3;
float* pf = &f;

// static cast<>
// OK, n = 12
int n = static_cast<int>(f);
// Error, types pointed to are unrelated
//int* pn = static_cast<int*>(pf);
// OK
void* pv = static_cast<void*>(pf);
// OK, but *pn2 is rubbish
int* pn2 = static_cast<int*>(pv);

// reinterpret_cast<>
// Error, the compiler know you should
// call static_cast<>
//int i = reinterpret_cast<int>(f);
// OK, but *pn is actually rubbish, same as *pn2
int* pi = reinterpret_cast<int*>(pf);
```

Courtesy:  [what static cast actually doing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12935/What-static-cast-is-actually-doing)
And you can not user `char*`  to point to a value of any type.